GCPのCE (Compute Engine) でVM料金が計算ツールで算出したものと請求額が異なる
GCPのCompute Engine（CE）でVMを作成し、利用しております。
料金が発生するたびに、事前に計算ツールで算出した料金よりも倍以上の請求額が届きます。
上記問題の原因がわかる方、いらっしゃいましたらご教示いただけますと幸いです。
詳細
VMインスタンスの種類: e2-micro
リージョン: us-west1-b
OS: Ubuntu22.04
バランス永続ディスク
サイズ:30GB
発生している料金: (具体的に発生している料金を記載):5/1~21 : 1191円
計算ツールで算出した料金: (計算ツールで算出した料金を記載)： $6.11


5/11 以降に費用が大幅に増えているように見えます。この辺りで、何か運用上の変化はありましたか？

返信ありがとうございます。運用状況について変更はございません。
私も調査を進め、Googleへ問い合わせを行いました。
e2-microインスタンスの場合、1インスタンスあたり月720時間までが無料枠として提供されます。5月11日以降、この無料枠が適用されなくなりました。
インスタンスのみ稼働している状況ですので、720時間（24時間×30日）を超えることはないと思われます。しかしながら、11日で無料枠を超えている原因は現時点では特定できておりません。
